# Why there is no block for showing algorithm/pseudocode in beamer?

Tags: beamer, block

Although there are many blocks in beamer, but I don't find any `algorithm`/`pseudo-code` block.

Why there is no `algorithm` block? Or, Is there any alternative block for algorithm? Or, Is block for algorithm bad typography?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
    This is a example block
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{Alert}
    This is a alert block
  \end{alertblock}
  \begin{theorem}{This is a theorem block}
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{definition}{This is a definition block}
  \end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As stated, this should probably be closed. Why there is none can only be answered by Beamer's author (or a close friend and motivational confidant). Whether it is bad typography is really a matter of opinion and better asked on graphics design se. But presumably Beamer just provides a few environments - most commonly needed, say - partly for use and partly as examples. Just as `amsthm` or whatever provides some out-of-the-box - most commonly used, perhaps - partly for use and partly as examples. Beamer allows you to extend it as you require and can't provide everything everyone might want.

Comment: Why questions are really not the best questions to be asked on this site. If you for example want to know how to create a new kind of block for `algorithm` this would be a good questions which would also be answerable by people which are not Till Tantau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic `block` environment can handle arbitrary block names. Including a pseudocode (or real code) example is as easy as:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{block}{Algorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}
  for i in range(10):
      foo(arg1, arg2)
  bar = qux()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, where there is no special block, general block can be used if requirement is fulfilled.